# insert text into scrolled text box outside of class

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to insert a text into textbox from within a function outside of class because i'm using threading.

code:

```
import os
import glob
import threading
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import ScrolledText as tkst


def searchfunc(string, filetype, directory):
    print 'string : '+string
    print 'filetype : '+filetype
    print 'directory : '+directory
    os.chdir(directory)
    for file in glob.glob('*'+filetype):
        if string in open(file).read():
            print '[-info-] textstring found in >> '+file
            searchresults.insert(INSERT, file) # problem line
        else:
            print '[-info-] text string not found in : '+file
            pass

class name:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
    ...
    def search():
        string = self.stringtextbox.get()
        filetype = self.filetypetextbox.get()
        directory = self.directorytextbox.get()
        t = threading.Thread(target=searchfunc(string, filetype, directory))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
```

But it give me the following error :

```
NameError: global name 'searchresults' is not defined
```

and ofcourse if i used the name "self.searchresults" will give me an error as well because as you know self is a discriptor within the class itself

Comment: I do not fully understand what you want but if a function `searchfunc` needs to call a method on `searchresults` then it probably should take `searchresults` as a parameter.

Comment: Oh, but i do not think updating the GUI from a different thread will work.

Comment: change `t = threading.Thread(target=searchfunc, args=(string, filetype, directory))`

Comment: what is `searchresults`?

Comment: Thank you @Goyo , Simply i'm trying to insert a variable/text into a tkinter text box but from inside a function outside the main class (because its a thread outside class in first place).

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc
I tried changing the line you provided but the arguments variables will be initiated/have their values set from the searchfunc function itself
Maybe another solution is to redirect console output to textbox directly
or, make the task done inside the main class directly but it might freeze the gui for a while, thats why i'm using threading.

Comment: @SarahJohnson No, you are confusing yourself, in your code you are evaluating the function in the main thread, if you want to run a thread you must pass the name of the function, not the evaluated function and the arguments as indicated: `t = threading.Thread(target=searchfunc, args=(string, filetype, directory))`. 
the thread is responsible for calling the function and passing the arguments in the new thread. 
this does not solve your current question but it helps, to solve your current problem I need you to answer: where have you created or declared to searchresults?

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc
I created "searchresults" later in the main class ... here : 
`        self.searchresults = tkst.ScrolledText(
    master = self.Labelframe2,
    wrap   = 'word', 
    width  = 70,      
    height = 10,      
    bg='white'        
)
        self.searchresults.pack()`

Comment: @SarahJohnson If you want help we need you to provide a [mcve], your current code is far from it, work on it and we will be happy to help you. :)

Comment: okay, Thanks, I just wanted to give a short summary of my code in my question to save reader's time :)
I will update my orignal question and post the whole code in a few seconds
I greatly appreciate your help

Comment: @SarahJohnson as I said I do not think updating the GUI from a different thread will work. Tkinter is not thread safe so all GUI code should be in the main thread.

Comment: @SarahJohnson please read carefully, a [mcve] is not the same as "the whole code". Posting a wall of code with a lot of irrelevent details won't help at all.

Comment: @Goyo ok got it, Thanks, appreciate your reminder :)
btw, i managed to solve the issue by just running the function inside the main  thread and it didn't freeze/block the gui as i expected, But for long running processes if i ever needed them later i will have to use an outside thread without updating gui at all i guess.